# Flex 3 How to Inspect value of Object

Tags: apache-flex, object

I'm debugging a problem and I've got:

```
o = URLUtil.stringToObject(browserManager.fragment);
```

When I try to put an alert on the var o, I get `[object] [object]`.

How do I find out its value?

Answer (score 1):

How about monster debugger? [De MonsterDebugger](http://demonsterdebugger.com/) It's beautiful and handy.

I was going to write out instructions but really this page is awesome: [Instructions](http://demonsterdebugger.com/features/howitworks)

Answer (score 1):

From Actionscript reference :

```
var myObject:Object = {firstName:"Tara", age:27, city:"San Francisco"}; 
for (var prop in myObject) { 
    trace("myObject."+prop+" = "+myObject[prop]); 
} 
/*
myObject.firstName = Tara 
myObject.age = 27 
myObject.city = San Francisco
*/
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import mx.utils.*;
trace(ObjectUtil.toString(myObject));
```